# Parametro "variable..." en metodos

Tags: java, variables

Buenas, me he topado con un nuevo estilo de variables al usar la clase FileNameExtensionFilter. El constructor que use tiene 2 parámetros tipo String solo que el segundo es diferente a los que ya conosco, este admite un conjunto de variables tipo String.

```
public void metodo(String str, String... Strs)
```

¿Me podrían dar información sobre ese estilo de parametro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se denomina `varargs`, `...` , indica que pueden llegar `n` (multiples) parametros de tipo String. En este caso un array de strings.

por ejemplo:

```
public void miMetodo(String... valores) {
...
...
}
```

Puedes llamar el método de distintas formas:

```
miMetodo("Asahi");

miMetodo("Asahi", "Shara");

miMetodo("Asahi", "Shara", "Elena");
```

Mas información :  [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)

Comment: Gracias por la información, me pondré a estudiarlo.

Comment: en la documentacion vienen ejemplos, únicamente que la información es en inglés.